# Как сделать папку системной?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сделать папку системной чтобы там появился файл desktop.ini?

Comment: редактируйте `ini`, что у вас конкретно не получается?

Comment: А можно с этого места про ini по подробней?

Comment: @babaykalopay, 1 - наличие desktop.ini не делает папку системной. 2 - просто создайте в папке desktop.ini с нужным содержимым.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выполнить в консоли `attrib +s namefolder`

Answer (score 1):

Папка не будет системной просто тем, что в ней будет `desktop.ini` - вы вероятно имеете в виду *системный атрибут* этого файла.

*Когда вы измените какие-то свойства папки* (нажмите правой кнопкой мыши, свойства), например измените её икону, скрытый и системный файл `desktop.ini` *автоматически возникнет*.